# Print without newline

Tags: printing, basic, gw-basic

In BASIC I know of two instructions to print to the screen, `PRINT`, and `WRITE`, both of which automatically print strings with a newline at the end. I want to print a string without a newline. How can I do this? I'm using GW-BASIC.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `PRINT` with a semicolon will not print a new line:

```
10 REM The trailing semicolon prevents a newline
20 PRINT "Goodbye, World!";
```

Source: [Rosettacode](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Newline_omission)

Comment: Yes, that is correct and I gave you credit for that. However, it doesn't work in Business Basic. Please see this URL: :http://documentation.basis.com/BASISHelp/WebHelp/commands2/print_verb.htm

Comment: Just found out that in Business Basic instead of using a semicolon (;) we have to use a comma (,)